# matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 160 is different from 40)

Tags: python, linear-regression

,i know it occur when the shape of the columns of train dataset is 3 and when the columns of test dataset is 2 .but when i have the same number of columns of train and test dataset even after that the error is occuring

```
y_pred = lr.predict(x_test)
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

after getting these error , i reshape it (-1,1) then it give another problem (matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 160 is different from 40)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-ed3d22f24031> in <module>
----> 1 y_pred = lr.predict(x_test)
      2 from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
      3 r2_score(y_test,y_pred)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in predict(self, X)
    234             Returns predicted values.
    235         """
--> 236         return self._decision_function(X)
    237 
    238     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    216         check_is_fitted(self)
    217 
--> 218         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    219         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
    220                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    617             # If input is 1D raise error
    618             if array.ndim == 1:
--> 619                 raise ValueError(
    620                     "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray={}.\n"
    621                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[6.63 7.25 7.36 5.95 7.93 8.35 7.3  6.22 7.32 7.87 5.11 5.88 8.21 6.59
 7.84 7.09 5.84 7.37 5.58 7.56 6.06 6.84 7.57 6.79 7.6  5.61 4.26 6.51
 7.33 5.84 8.31 6.94 8.2  6.97 6.3  7.62 6.1  7.14 9.06 6.94].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Often sklearn needs non flat array, therefore the reshape error. To me is not clear does the second error happen in the same function? Can you provide the shapes for the predictions and the true labels.

Comment: x=dff['cgpa']
y=dff['package'] second line :--X=np.array([x]),Y=np.array([y]) #i have converted to np array because it is show to reshape therefore i use np.array.The data set contain only two columns and 100rows                                                                                                                  x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,
                                              random_state=42)                                          lr.fit(np.array([x_train]),[(y_train)]) ----it run sucessfully but when i predict it show me the error

Comment: It would be great if you could include that in your post. Maybe try just `np.array(x_train)`, else you nest it in another array.

Comment: sir it is not working .